# WinForms button position - not aligned as it should

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, position

Adding some gui modifications and I want to have a button which is 10pixels away from the forms left and right border. With this code the right border of the button is around 20-30 pixel outside the form window. Why is that? How can I position  my button to be exactly 10pixels away from the form borders ?

```
int margin = 10;
meny1 = new Button();
meny1.Top = 50;
meny1.Left = margin;
meny1.Size = new Size(this.Width - (2*margin), 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate with `this.ClientWidth` although I would expect the difference to be just the BorderSize, not 20 pixels.

Comment: Will do that in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Form.ClientWidth`.  This code worked for me.

```
button1.Left = 10;
button1.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 20;
```

Comment: That worked just fine. Didnt even notice there was the client "space". Thank you.